# malayalam word sense disambiguation in python

Tags: python

```
# encoding=utf-8
file=open("mm.txt","r+")
wordcount={}
for word in file.read().split():
    if word not in wordcount:
        wordcount[word] = 1
    else:
        wordcount[word] += 1
print (word,wordcount)
file.close();
```

This work fine for english sentence 
how to work this code for malayalam sentence

Comment: check fro this malayalam sentence    ദൈവം തെറ്റ് തെറ്റ്.

Comment: can u help me to get the code i'm new to python and malayalam nlp

Comment: (u'\u0d24\u0d46\u0d31\u0d4d\u0d31\u0d4d.', {u'\u0d24\u0d46\u0d31\u0d4d\u0d31\u0d4d': 1, u'\u0d24\u0d46\u0d31\u0d4d\u0d31\u0d4d.': 1, u'\u0d26\u0d48\u0d35\u0d02': 1})

Comment: http://ideone.com/OxsabI

Comment: File "ideone_OxsabI.py", line 4
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe0' in file ideone_OxsabI.py on line 4, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

Comment: this is what we get as output

Comment: I think you missed the `# encoding=utf-8` line

Comment: yes it works :) now what we want is when we give  malayalam sentence as input we need to find out how many times each word occur in that text file(these text file contains malayalam words)

Comment: There is no error in your problem. Only thing is dont try to print the dictionary as such. Iterate and print. The `print` will do the unicode encoding for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to **include encoding (utf-8)** while opening the file

```
import codecs
with codecs.open("mm.txt",encoding="utf-8") as f:
   wordcount={}
     for word in f.read().split():
```

this will work